# Launch mobile native app from browser

Tags: android, facebook, mobile

First of all please bear me with this if this question doesn't make sense (as I don't have mobile app knowledge). What I am trying to do is I have Facebook share button in my web application. Everything works fine on web and mobile but only thing I want to achieve is:

On mobile browser when you click on share button, instead of opening that URL in browser native Facebook mobile app should be launched.

This is what I have currently on share link:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://domain.com" class="facebook" target="_blank"></a>
```

I tried something I found on google as below but didn't work:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://domain.com" data-applink="fb://profile" class="facebook" target="_blank" ></a>
```